# How can i configurate global sass variables in defineNuxtModule available in components?

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I wish to make global sass variables in defineNuxtModule for my components (Nuxt 3)

I'm using Nuxt 3 and now trying to make my own module. But i don't get how can i make global sass variables for my components. I know it's possible in nuxt.config.ts for a common project but how to configurate it to your module. ChatGPT says something like this:

```
export default defineNuxtModule({
  build: {
    loaders: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `
          @import "@/assets/scss/variables.scss";
        `,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

but it doesn't work. Can somebody help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Vite builder is working under the hood of nuxt3. So you should try this one

`nuxt.config.ts`

```
vite: {
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          additionalData: `
            @import "@/assets/scss/variables.scss";
          `
        }
      }
    }
  }
```